# rpm fails to install gtest

Tags: linux, centos, googletest, libc

while installing gtest on centos using rpm gives following error

> #rpm -Uvh gtest-1.6.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
>  
>   warning: gtest-1.6.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 352c64e5: NOKEY
>   error: Failed dependencies:
>       libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by gtest-1.6.0-2.el7.x86_64

while locating libc.so.6 got following result

> # locate libc.so.6
>   /lib/libc.so.6
>   /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
>   /lib64/libc.so.6

Should i specify library path for rpm?

I am new to centos.please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to CentOS 7, the first version which provides the `GLIBC_2.14` symbol version in glibc.